# How to bind JSON response from httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I can httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(path, content) fine.

However, this post returns some JSON with details of the response, eg:
{"StatusCode":200,"AccessCode":"92BEEB285ZB47DA","InternalMessage":null}

I need to access the AccessCode.

How can I do this cleanly and efficiently? Can I create an object like this:

```
public class GIResponse
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string AccessCode { get; set; }
    public string InternalMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And map it to the result?

Or how would I just traverse the JSON and pull out the AccessCode?

I have searched quite extensively but surprisingly I can't find anything on Google - perhaps as this is the result from a Post, not a Get.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you get the `responseText` using `httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync`, you can use Json.NET's `JObject` and define it as dynamic:

```
dynamic j = JObject.Parse(@"{""StatusCode"":200,""AccessCode"":""92BEEB285ZB47DA"",""InternalMessage"":null}");
Console.WriteLine(j.AccessCode);
```

Also you can use `JsonConvert`:

```
var result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyModel>(resposeText);
```

Obviously, if you already have a model, you do not read it as a string and you can simply read it as your model:

```
var result = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>();
```

Comment: Thanks! what if model is not known and we need return just JSON object? Incase of web api